# Color is not changing when setting theming color programmatically

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using a headless forge-viewer (version 6.*) and I can't set theming color in a specific element. After viewer loading, I select some elements programmatically and try to set their theming colors using setThemingColor function but nothing is happening.

When I try to set their theming colors via console (using NOP_VIEWER), it changes but only after calling the method twice with different parameters, something like:

```
NOP_VIEWER.setThemingColor(4238, new THREE.Vector4(1, 1, 1, 1));
NOP_VIEWER.setThemingColor(4238, new THREE.Vector4(0, 1, 1, 1));
```

What I'm doing in my code is (this.viewer3D is an instance of Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D):

```
this.viewer3D.clearThemingColors();

const currentSelection = this.viewer3D.getSelection();
currentSelection.forEach((id: number) =>
  this.viewer3D.setThemingColor(id, new THREE.Vector4(0, 1, 1, 1))
);
```

Is there any other way that I can change these element colors?

Comment: `setThemingColor` is the way to go, make sure you are on the latest v6.6 and see live code [here](https://jsbin.com/disopoq/edit?html), except if you need to set the color recursively for all child nodes you can flip the recursive flag to true like `` - but don't that was the catch here so can you send the model through to forge.help@autodesk.com if possible (via a sharing service like weTransfer/Dropbox) so we can try to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks for replying, Bryan Huang. I've just sent an e-mail with the model we're using for testing to forge.help@autodesk via weTransfer. As soon as we solve it, I'll post the solution here and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed a very similar issue replacing

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

with

```js
const THREE = window.THREE;
```